# Typescript `ensureArray` helper generic type

Tags: typescript

I would like to create helper function that will ensure that value is wrapped in array.

- if value is `null` or `undefined` return empty array
- if value is array, leave it as is
- else wrap value in array

[Typescript sandbox](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUzAZxAJ2QQU5gQwE8AeAFQD4AKAWAChFEA3AgGxGQC5EyAaegJTcyKAB5RUAEzSJwk5MBhhkkxAB9EYEK1aIA-IgDaAXUTCxEsNMR5CpAmCIV9PMzxOIA3vUYxgiKhZ2ZEQAXnDZKwUlFXUNII4wiK0dAS8fRkQAeiyeIgAHEIByEyLEGBkwOChEAjQ0GABzMAIAI1YQqDhEKALikWRxKUrtXQ05aOVVAw9zQctrByIPAxFhUoA6KgAmAGZt7YEMxmwoLCQTAG5s3LQACzhtVQBJRAArEDQaz5C62sc9BkAL70DI5PKFRBFKgiABk-2WxjSGkMZGMZQqmmqtXqTRa7U63V6kKKAyGVhGOnUkXkiimLlmrnmwwRK1c63RGzBuQh-UQ8KWpXKlWxdQazTaHR6RL6ULJC0pYxpk1iM1Mc3Ji0cbLW7k5O32hwyp3ONnwxA2FVsxECbA4aQMCRC3EMTuMl3oILooLoEAQX0QogAjNwtABbVrITAeUIodBYXDmohUINHX3%20mqibahkARqMxuMYbDW5OGIO8RDbJH0P3oTO7bhfTBKRoeFGmWOoIuJuxUIpNsp-Jst6kpVhpoA).

What I don't understand is what is typescript complains about, how to fix it and is there a way to get more descriptive error message:

```
function ensureArray<T>(
  value: T,
): T extends undefined | null ? [] : T extends Array<any> ? T : T[] {
  if (value === undefined || value === null) {
    // Type '[]' is not assignable to type 'T extends null | undefined ? [] : T extends any[] ? T : T[]'.(2322)
    return []; // should I just use as any?
  }

  // Type '(T & any[]) | [T]' is not assignable to type 'T extends null | undefined ? [] : T extends any[] ? T : T[]'.
  //  Type 'T & any[]' is not assignable to type 'T extends null | undefined ? [] : T extends any[] ? T : T[]'.(2322)
  return Array.isArray(value) ? value : [value];
}


const x1: number[] = ensureArray(1)
const x2: number[] = ensureArray([1, 2])
const x3: string[] | [] = ensureArray('str' as string | null)
```

Comment: TypeScript does not support conditional types in a place of return type. In this case it worth to overload your function. See [example](https://tsplay.dev/mLlxkm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the conditional type !

```
function ensureArray<T>(
  value: T | Array<T> | undefined | null,
): T[] {
  if (value === undefined || value === null) {
    return []; // should I just use as any?
  }

  return Array.isArray(value) ? value : [value];
}


const x1: number[] = ensureArray(1)
const x2: number[] = ensureArray([1, 2])
const x3: string[] = ensureArray('str' as string | null)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUzAZxAJ2QQU5gQwE8AeAFQD4AKAWAChFEA3AgGxGQC5EzEAfRHkKlK-ROAAmyYDDDIJYsCFasANPQCU3MgG0AuogDe9RjGCIqLdskQBee+LBSZchXwFWOdh0pUajJoyI2FBYSPoA3IiBAL70gSFhgvjEAHQwaELElmwc-gD8zLk23DqeyHoR9HF08XQQCGhQiAAeAIzcSgC2AEbImPp2KOhYuClEVG0a9A3ozS0ATJ0gvf2DtsMY2FkTOm2qiAt60-WN8wDM3E2YsgDm65ujO1QA5NcviARoiNd3isqsE5AA)

Comment: Thanks, can you explain why condition is not working?

Comment: `ensureArray(null)` returns `null[]`, whereas it should be `[]`. Hence, I believe there should be some conditional logic inder the hood

Comment: `null[]`  would be correct to me, there is no way the compiler can infer something out of a null parameter.

Comment: @ZiiMakc Typescript does control-flow type narrowing on regular variables, but not on type variables like your T.